# Some statements under if condition are not getting executed while some are getting executed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a small program for randomly playing pacman on openai-gym. But its acting wierdly, only one statement is being executed under the if condition. The game is not rendering (maybe because env.reset()) is not executing.

```
import gym

episode = 0
#episode_reward = 0
#running_reward = None
env = gym.make("MsPacman-v0")
env.reset()


while True:
    env.render()
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    #print (action)
    _, __, done, ___ = env.step(action)
    #print(reward)
    #episode_reward += reward

    if done:
        print('Game over')              #Why is this line not printed
        episode = episode + 1           #Why is episode not getting updated
        #running_reward = episode_reward if running_reward is None else  running_reward * 0.99 + episode_reward * 0.01
        #print('Episode %d, episode reward total was %f. running mean: %f' % (episode, episode_reward, running_reward))
        print('Episode, ', episode)      #Only this line is printed on screen
        #episode_reward = 0
        env.reset()
```

Just hoping I am not making some silly mistake!

Comment: Yes its the exact same code. I am using python 2.7.13

Comment: [Link to screen-shot](https://i.imgur.com/PqIQO0S.png). Hope this will make it more believable.

Comment: @PrabhatDoongarwal Is it possible you have some `.pyc` files around in the directory, and you're actually executing an earlier version of the script? Alternatively, is it possible that the `(Episode, '0')` output is coming from either `env.action_space.sample()` or `env.step(action)`?

Comment: Consider changing `print('Episode ', episode)` to `print('Test', episode)` and see if the output changes.

Comment: @Paul No .pyc file exist in the folder and I have run it many times. Also, copied the file to new folder an ran that, output remains same. 
No, it is not possible to get that output from either of the statements you mentioned. [link to openai gym docs](https://gym.openai.com/docs/). You can also check docs, that none of the statements do that.

Comment: @Paul Output changes. [Link to screen-shot](https://i.imgur.com/LZxKG4P.png)

Comment: @PrabhatDoongarwal This is bizarre. Is it possible this is a whitespace thing? I'm not sure if there's valid whitespace mixing that would give you this result, but possibly everything after line 23 is not in the `if` block at all. Can you add `print(done)` *after* the `print('Test')` statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158277/discussion-between-prabhat-doongarwal-and-paul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158277/discussion-between-prabhat-doongarwal-and-paul), it seems that your file had a mixture of tabs and spaces in it, which was leading the block to look visually contiguous, but interpret as two separate blocks (one in the `if` block and one out of it).

Apparently this is because the `while` loop is indented with tabs, but the  last part of the `if` block that does *not* include the `print` statement uses *only* spaces. So it goes:

```
\t___if done:
\t___....print('Game over')
\t___....episode = episode + 1
 ........print('Episode ', episode)
 ........env.reset()
```

So this is being interpreted as equivalent to:

```
if done:
    # Start of block
    print('Game over')              #Why is this line not printed
    episode = episode + 1           #Why is episode not getting updated
    # End of block

print('Episode, ', episode)      #Only this line is printed on screen
#episode_reward = 0
env.reset()
```

Probably something to keep in mind if there's ever a python analog to the [Underhanded C competition](http://www.underhanded-c.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a mixture of tabs and spaces. (I checked by clicking "edit" under your post and copying the text to an editor.)

Replace all the tabs with spaces and it should fix the problem.

[image]